# Physcial interpretation of term neglected in Rotating Wave Approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-optics, absorption

Consider an atom as a two-level system $|1\rangle, |2\rangle$ with energy separation $\hbar \omega_0$, which is interacting with a classical electric field $\vec{E}=\vec{E}_0 \cos(\omega t)$. This semi-classical approach leads to the probablity to find the atom in the excited state at a time $t$ (see e.g. [Foot Atomic Physics](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/atomic-physics-9780198506966)):
$$P_2 (t) \propto \frac{1-e^{i(\omega_0+\omega)t}}{\omega_0+\omega} + \frac{1-e^{i(\omega_0-\omega)t}}{\omega_0-\omega}.$$
Note the different signs in the exponents. The first term is usually neglected by choosing the so-called "Rotating Wave Approximation", or RWA for short, since it often holds that $\omega \approx \omega_0$. However, the interpretation of this term is the following: When the atom is initially in the ground state $|1\rangle$, it can **emit** a photon of frequency $\omega$ and transition into the **excited** state $|2\rangle$. How is this physically possible? My understanding was that a photon needs to be *absorbed* in order for the atom to undergo a transition to an energetically higher state and not emit a photon while doing so.

Comment: The sign in the exponents is the same.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Hamiltonian that leads to the probability expression that you've written? if you do it will become obvious why the neglected term is said to correspond to emitting a photon while the atom jumps up one level. Also, by the way, it's really weird to refer to the ground state as 1; usually we call the ground state 0.